# Download blob from Azure Storage with SAS

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I am having a hard time figuring out how to download a blob from Azure storage using .net and a generated Shared Access Signature token.

First of all, most of the tutorials I could find are using  `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage` nuget  package, which is deprecated. Instead I use the newest `Azure.Storage.Blobs` package.

I have the following code so far. I don't know what to do with the generated SAS token. How do I download the blob from there ?

```
  [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Download([FromQuery] string blobUri)
    {
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(this.configuration.GetConnectionString("StorageAccount"));


        // Create a SAS token that's valid for one hour.
        BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
        {
            BlobContainerName = "my container name",
            BlobName = blobUri,
            Resource = "b",
            StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
            ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
        };

        // Specify read permissions for the SAS.
        sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read);

        // Use the key to get the SAS token.
        var sasToken = sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(new Azure.Storage.StorageSharedKeyCredential("my account name", "my account key"));



        BlobClient blob = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("my container name").GetBlobClient($"{blobUri}");
        await using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await blob.DownloadToAsync(memoryStream);
           return File(memoryStream, "file");
        }

    }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would want to download blob using SAS URI. Correct? Also, what's the `blobUri` parameter? Is it the name of the blob or it's URL?

Comment: if you already have the account key in there, why do you want to generate a SAS token? why not just using the key to download?

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS, correct. And the blobUri parameter is the blog URL.

Comment: @silent, I'm not sure how to use the account key to download the file ? Besides, this is just a POC for now, I will eventually remove this key from the source code and I want to use SAS token as a more secured way

Comment: Sam...You can't really get rid of account key as it is required to generate a SAS token.

Comment: @silent...You want to do the honors of answering the question :)?

Comment: I should add that  `blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("upp").GetBlobClient($"{blobUri}");` does return the blob. However `blob.Download()` returns the error "The specified blob does not exist"

Comment: I figured it out. This is because, as mentioned earlier, the blogUri is the URL and not the name. But `GetBlobClient` expects the name of the blob. Since the calling application only knows abou the blob's URL, is there a way to create BlobClient  from URL instead of Name ?

Comment: @Sam, just a quick question on sas token, did you find solution on how to use the token while downloading the blob

Comment: In the end I have used aad authentication to connect to storage. I have no use for sas anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the official github repo you find great example using various means of authentication. Using account key in the [sample is called SharedKey](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/samples/Sample02_Auth.cs#L98). There is also a [sample to use SAS tokens](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/samples/Sample02_Auth.cs#L137) - but those you need to generate somehow. Usually you do this using the account key...

The other option - and what I would recommend to use if possible, is to use [AAD (Azure Active Directory)-based aut](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/samples/Sample02_Auth.cs#L191)h. In this case you don't need either account keys or SAS tokens.

See here for the various samples:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/samples/Sample02_Auth.cs

Comment: yes I've seen these samples and if you check my code you can see I'm using the same approach. My question is related to the actual download of the file from the blob container. How do I use the generated SAS token to download the file ?